# How do I export all AD users but only specific columns

Tags: powershell

I am stuck on this: I only want to export these fields from the AD users:
`Department`,`EmployeeNumber`,`Title`,`Email`,`Address`,`DisplayName`

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department,EmployeeNumber,Title,Email,Address,DisplayName |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Ad.csv'
```

Is that possible with Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to return only the desired properties:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department,EmployeeNumber,Title,Email,Address,DisplayName |
    Select-Object Department,EmployeeNumber,Title,Email,Address,DisplayName |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Ad.csv'
```